# What formula would you use for the following probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, hypergeometric-function

Working on a card game, and trying to balance the deck by writing a simulation software to cut down on the number of playtests I need to conduct. I'm using hypergeometric probability for many of the heuristics I'm solving for, but not sure how to solve this case

I want to know what the probability of a player drawing N copies of a card at the start of the game. As an example:

You have a deck of **40 cards**, with **4 copies** of **Card A**. **3 people** are playing, and they **each draw 7 cards** to start the game. What are the **odds that any player has a pair of Card A** to start?

As a slightly more challenging question beyond that, how could I calculate this for a class of cards?:

You have a deck of **40 cards**, with **4 copies each** of **Card A**, **Card B**, and **Card C**. **3 people** are playing, and they **each draw 7 cards** to start the game. What are the **odds that any player has a pair of any the three types of cards** listed to start?

Comment: Are all players drawing from the same deck, or each have a seperate deck of 40 cards?

Comment: Typically problems of this type can be solve by computing probability of it not happening and subtract from one.

Comment: All players drawn from the same deck.  And Herb I still don't know how to calculate the probability of not drawing the desired cards